# Mail to opening from text

Tags: email, popup

If possible, I want to have a few words of text (a question) sitting on a page in SharePoint 2013, which when clicked, automatically opens in a pop-up window, an email template (To: with the address line completed) with some of the body of the email containing other text.]

Is this possible?
If yes, how?
Have tried searching for this but not getting anywhere so far.

Thanks very much in advance.

Amy

Comment: If your end goal is to collect data/opinions/input from  your users, you could look into using SharePoint 2013's Survey app.

Comment: Why not use a `mailto` link, if all you want is to open an email?

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard anchor as a mailto that you would include by using the modify hmtl button, http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aabegin100299.htm.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@mydomain.com&subject="Site%20Feedback"&body="A%20prefilled%20body">Click to email</a>
```

Comment: The only thing that is bad with pre-entered body is that it kills the senders signature. :)